# Stop Mapbox GL JS Zoom Event

Tags: mapbox, zooming, mapbox-gl-js

I have a zoom listener in my mapbox gl (1.10) application

```
this.map.on('zoom' e => {
  if (suchAndSuch()) {
    stopTheZoomFromHappening(e);
  }
})
```

I have tried `e.originalEvent.preventDefault()`, and `e.originalEvent.stopPropagation()`. I have also tried listening to the `zoomstart` event. The zoom is not cancelled.

I know there is `disableScrollZoom`, and other `disable<type>Zoom`, but it seems cumbersome to disable, enable in this way.

Is there a way to stop a single zoom event from having an effect on the map?